# Prove that a canonical bundle is trivial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $y \in Reg(f), M=f^{-1}(y)$. Prove that the canonical bundle of M is trivial.

I have an hint but I don't know how to use it: consider the open subset $M_i = \{p \in M \colon \frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i} \ne 0 \}$. Try to define $\omega_i \in \Omega^{n-1}(M)$ so that for all $p \in M_i$

$\omega_p =(-1)^i \frac {(dx_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_{i-1}\wedge dx_{i+1}\wedge ... \wedge dx_n)_p}  {\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}}$.

Comment: If you believe the hint, then $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \omega_i$ is a nonvanishing section of the canonical bundle, and this implies that it is trivial since it is a line bundle.  Is this what you were asking, or do you need help with the hint itself?

Comment: @PaulSiegel thank for your answer. Only another thing: why that identify a non vanishing section? How i can prove that is non vanishing?

Comment: Well, $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \omega_i = \sum_i (-1)^i dx_1 \wedge \ldots \hat{dx_i} \wedge \ldots dx_n$.  If you pair this with any $n-1$ distinct tangent vectors in the set $\partial x_1, \ldots, \partial x_n$ then all but one term in the sum goes away and you are left with $\pm 1$.

Comment: @PaulSiegel you are my favourite teacher! :-)

Comment: @PaulSiegel Only a precisation. For show that is a trivial bundle I have to show that there are n-1 section independet...here we find only one section...

Comment: $M$ has dimension $n-1$, so the space of forms of degree $n-1$ is one dimensional.

Comment: @PaulSiegel Oh yes...sorry for the question!